# Every professor bores some of his/her students

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

This is the statement we need to translate into predicate logic:

> Every professor bores some of his/her students.

- $P(x)$: $x$ is a professor.
- $S(x,y)$: $x$ is a student of $y$.
- $B(x,y)$: $x$ bores $y$.

I came up with

$$\forall x \exists y \left( P(x) \land S (y,x) \to B(x,y) \right)$$

but the answer in the solutions is

$$\forall x \exists y \left( P(x) \to S (y,x) \land B(x,y) \right)$$

Why is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: What you've written is satisfied if a professor has no students at all (which is arguably a valid interpretation of the original English sentence). More to the point, any $y$ that is not a student of $x$ satisfies the bound formula.

Comment: Oh, didn't look at it that way lol, I thought he was trying to convey something regarding the question!

Comment: @anomaly So are you saying that in my answer if S(y,x) is false (there exists no students of x) then my statement still ends up being true(since the assumption is false and because it is an implication the entire statement is true), even if those y are not students?

Comment: Any $y$ for which $S(y, x)$ fails will satisfy the statement in brackets.

Comment: @anomaly thanks for the response, but even if we look at this ∀x∃y(P(x)→S(y,x)∧B(x,y)), wouldn't this be satisfied even when x is not a professor? ie. when P(x) is False?

Comment: Yes it would, @NikshepSvn but that is okay. We want $\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))$ to mean that *any* arbitrary person either *is not a professor* or *is a professor for whom* $Q(x)$ is true.  And here, $Q(x)$ is the existance of a student of $x$ whom $x$ bores.

Comment: Yes, but that's fine. In English, it would read, "For every professor $x$, there exists a student $y$ bored by $x$."

Answer (score 0):

Remember than an implication $p \to q$ evaluates to True whenever $p$ is False. In your answer, you only need to find a $y$ such that $P(x) \land S(y,x)$ is False for your implication $P(x) \land S(y,x) \to B(x,y)$ to evaluate to True.

In English, your implication would be satisfied if, for every professor, there were a person who was not a student of that professor (which seems like a reasonable assertion!), even if every professor had exactly zero bored students.

Comment: thanks for the response, but even if we look at this ∀x∃y(P(x)→S(y,x)∧B(x,y)), wouldn't this be satisfied even when x is not a professor? ie. when P(x) is False?

Comment: Yes. But the statement you're asked to convert really is "If she is a professor, then she bores some of her students." If you look at the form of this question, it *only* makes claims about people (in the logic statements, the $x$) who are professors. If $x$ is not a professor, then the premise of the implication is not satisfied, so we have nothing to say about $x$. This is an example of "vacuous truth."